# Typescript Declaration File working with generics and merged objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I have created a configuration object checker function which basically checks that an object matches a blueprint. Very similar to how React Prop Types works. I will use this to automate app deployment across different websites with different configuration files to ensure the configuration file is correctly defined before attempting to deploy.

### It works like this:

I have a function that takes an object and returns a function.

#### Example:

```
const blueprint = {
stringValue: ConfigTypes.string, 
requirednumberValue: ConfigTypes.number.isRequired, 
boolOrStringValue: ConfigTypes.oneOfType([ConfigTypes.string, ConfigType.bool])
} //The syntax here is very similar to that of React Prop Types. I am essentially defining what I expect my object to look like.

const checker = ConfigChecker(blueprint)
```

`ConfigChecker` takes a blueprint of what keys we expect to be in the object and what the value types for the specified keys are, and whether they are optional or required. `ConfigChecker` returns a function which takes 2 objects as arguments.

#### Example:

```
const config = {
stringValue: "Hello"
boolOrStringValue: true
}
const defaults = {
requirednumberValue: 5,
boolOrStringValue: false
}
checker(config, defaults) //checker is defined in the above example. The return of ConfigChecker(blueprint)
```

The `config` argument is the configuration object we plan on using for the app, whereas, the `defaults` argument is the default key value pairs we can use for the app if they aren't specified in the configuration object.

Internally, the `config` argument and the `defaults` argument are deeply merged together with the configuration object overwriting same key values in the defaults object.

So the result of the above example would be:

```
{
stringValue: "Hello"
boolOrStringValue: true
requirednumberValue: 5,
}
```

After the 2 arguments have been merged they are tested against the `blueprint` to ensure the end configuration object containing the merged `default` and `config` objects is correctly defined.

The declaration file for this function looks like this:

```
interface Requireable {}
interface ConfigType {
  isRequired: Requireable;
}

type CType = {
  /**
   * A string value.
   */
  string: ConfigType;
  /**
   * A boolean value.
   */
  bool: ConfigType;
  /**
   * A number value.
   */
  number: ConfigType;
  /**
   * A function.
   */
  func: ConfigType;
  /**
   * An object. Not an array.
   */
  object: ConfigType;
  /**
   * An array.
   */
  array: ConfigType;
  /**
   * Any value.
   */
  any: ConfigType;
  /**
   * An array of a specific type.
   */
  arrayOf: (type: CType[keyof CType]) => ConfigType;
  /**
   * An object containing a specific type.
   */
  objectOfType: (type: CType[keyof CType]) => ConfigType;
  /**
   * One of these values.
   * @example
   * OneOf(["Hello", "Goodbye", false])
   */
  oneOf: (enums: Array<any>) => ConfigType;
  /**
   * One of these types.
   * @example
   * OneOf([ConfigType.string, ConfigType.number])
   */
  oneOfType: (types: Array<CType[keyof CType]>) => ConfigType;
  /**
   * An object with specific keys and value types.
   */
  objectOf: (obj: { [key: string]: CType[keyof CType] }) => ConfigType;
  /**
   * An object with specific keys and value types. The objects must strictly match.
   */
  exactObjectOf: (obj: { [key: string]: CType[keyof CType] }) => ConfigType;
};

/**
 * Check functions.
 */
export const ConfigTypes: CType;

type Id<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

type SpreadProperties<L, R, K extends keyof L & keyof R> = {
  [P in K]: L[P] | Exclude<R[P], undefined>;
};

type OptionalPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type Spread<L, R> = Id<
  // Properties in L that don't exist in R
  Pick<L, Exclude<keyof L, keyof R>> &
    // Properties in R with types that exclude undefined
    Pick<R, Exclude<keyof R, OptionalPropertyNames<R>>> &
    // Properties in R, with types that include undefined, that don't exist in L
    Pick<R, Exclude<OptionalPropertyNames<R>, keyof L>> &
    // Properties in R, with types that include undefined, that exist in L
    SpreadProperties<L, R, OptionalPropertyNames<R> & keyof L>
>;

export default function <S extends { [key: string]: CType[keyof CType] }>(
  schema: S
): <C extends { [key: string]: any }, D extends { [key: string]: any }>(
  config: C,
  defaults?: D
) => Pick<Spread<C, D>, keyof S>;
```

Essentially, what this declaration file is stating is that the resulting value of calling `ConfigChecker(blueprint)(config, defaults)` should be an object containing only the keys inside the `blueprint` object with the value types of those keys coming from the merged `config` and `defaults` objects. Therefore, if I were to add a key to the `config` object without first defining the key in the `blueprint` object, the returned object would not contain that added key; only the keys inside the `blueprint` object will be defined in the returned object.

While this works well, it is simply a workaround as to what i am really trying to do.

What I would really like to achieve from my declaration file is this:

Given the `blueprint` above, typescript should infer that the returned object, prior to providing a `config` and `defaults` object, should look like this:

```
{
stringValue?: string, 
requirednumberValue: number, 
boolOrStringValue?: boolean | string
}
```

Then, after the `config` and `defaults` objects have been added, typescript should cross reference them to the blueprint and return something like this:

```
{
stringValue: string, 
requirednumberValue: number, 
boolOrStringValue: boolean
}
```

So firstly, Typescript should infer that the return type of the function should be an object containing optional and required key/value pairs. These key/value pairs could be of multiple types, as is the case with: `boolOrStringValue?: boolean | string` which is both optional and could be a boolean or a string.

Lastly, Typescript should read the values within the merged `config` and `defaults` objects and replace the assumed types for the known types.

I know the first work around works fine, however, on top of this being a cool feature, it will also allow me to wrap my head around Typescript as I have only just started. I like throwing myself in the deep end by doing stuff like this. Can something like this be done or am I in over my head?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find my own solution. This is the new declaration file:

```
interface OConfigType<T> {
  isRequired: RConfigType<T>;
}

interface RConfigType<_T> {
  (): void;
}

type GetType<T> = T extends OConfigType<infer T> | RConfigType<infer T>
  ? T
  : never;

type CType = {
  /**
   * A string value.
   */
  string: OConfigType<string>;
  /**
   * A boolean value.
   */
  bool: OConfigType<boolean>;
  /**
   * A number value.
   */
  number: OConfigType<number>;
  /**
   * A function.
   */
  func: OConfigType<Function>;
  /**
   * An object. Not an array.
   */
  object: OConfigType<Object>;
  /**
   * An array.
   */
  array: OConfigType<Array<any>>;
  /**
   * Any value.
   */
  any: OConfigType<any>;
  /**
   * An array of a specific type.
   */
  arrayOf: <S>(type: S) => OConfigType<Array<GetType<S>>>;
  /**
   * An object containing a specific type.
   */
  objectOfType: <S>(
    type: S
  ) => OConfigType<Record<string | number, GetType<S>>>;
  /**
   * One of these values.
   * @example
   * OneOf(["Hello", "Goodbye", false])
   */
  oneOf: <T>(
    enums: [...T]
  ) => T extends Array<infer U> ? OConfigType<U> : never;
  /**
   * One of these types.
   * @example
   * OneOf([ConfigType.string, ConfigType.number])
   */
  oneOfType: <T>(types: [...T]) => T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never;
  /**
   * An object with specific keys and value types.
   */
  objectOf: <S extends { [key: string | number]: OConfigType | RConfigType }>(
    obj: S
  ) => OConfigType<ReturnSchema<S>>;
  /**
   * An object with specific keys and value types. The objects must strictly match.
   */
  exactObjectOf: <
    S extends { [key: string | number]: OConfigType | RConfigType }
  >(
    obj: S
  ) => OConfigType<ReturnSchema<S>>;
};

/**
 * Check functions.
 */
export const ConfigTypes: CType;

type Id<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

type SpreadProperties<L, R, K extends keyof L & keyof R> = {
  [P in K]: L[P] | Exclude<R[P], undefined>;
};

type OptionalPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type Spread<L, R> = Id<
  // Properties in L that don't exist in R
  Pick<L, Exclude<keyof L, keyof R>> &
    // Properties in R with types that exclude undefined
    Pick<R, Exclude<keyof R, OptionalPropertyNames<R>>> &
    // Properties in R, with types that include undefined, that don't exist in L
    Pick<R, Exclude<OptionalPropertyNames<R>, keyof L>> &
    // Properties in R, with types that include undefined, that exist in L
    SpreadProperties<L, R, OptionalPropertyNames<R> & keyof L>
>;

// export default function <S extends { [key: string]: CType[keyof CType] }>(
//   schema: S
// ): <C extends { [key: string]: any }, D extends { [key: string]: any }>(
//   config: C,
//   defaults?: D
// ) => Pick<Spread<C, D>, keyof S>;

//type ReturnType<S> =

type Filter<Base, Condition> = {
  [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never;
}[keyof Base];

type FilterReturnType<S> = {
  [Key in keyof S]: S[Key] extends OConfigType | RConfigType ? Key : never;
}[keyof S];

type GetReturnType<S> = {
  [Key in keyof S]: S[Key] extends OConfigType<infer T> | RConfigType<infer T>
    ? T
    : never;
};

type ReturnType<S> = GetReturnType<Pick<S, FilterReturnType<S>>>;

type ReturnSchema<S> = ReturnType<Pick<S, Filter<S, RConfigType<any>>>> &
  ReturnType<Partial<Pick<S, Filter<S, OConfigType<any>>>>>;

type ReturnConfig<S, C> = {
  [K in keyof S]: C[K];
};

interface ReturnFunction<S> {
  <C extends S, D extends S>(config: C, defaults?: D = {}): ReturnConfig<
    S,
    Spread<C, D>
  >;
}

export default function <
  S extends {
    [key: string | number]: OConfigType | RConfigType;
  }
>(schema: S): ReturnFunction<ReturnSchema<S>>;
```

This does most of what I was trying to achieve aside from reading the value of `config` and `defaults` to update the final object. But at least now the output of the function is based on the `blueprint` object you put in.

Now the expected input for both the `config` and `defaults` object is properly defined:

[image: VSCode Screenshot]

And the output object is properly defined.

[image: VSCode Screenshot]